# Pass data to redirect page JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, firebase-authentication

I use fire base auth with javascript
and i want to send client to his profile page using his id
i want to send the userId through the window.location.href

I tried jquery post request but i didnt know how to send or recieve the data properly

I need an easy solution to my problem,
Thanks.

```
$.post(
            "./index.html",
            {
              id: user.uid,
            },
            function (data, status) {
              alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            }
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

By using query parameters you can pass data to redirect URL `./index.html?userId=1` and inside that page

you should have a read query parameter logic like.,

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
for (const param of params) {
  console.log(param)
}
```

I hope this solutions will work in your case